# How to create a list from another list using specific criteria in Python?

Tags: python, list

How can I create a list from another list using python?
If I have a list:

```
input = ['a/b', 'g', 'c/d', 'h', 'e/f']
```

How can I create the list of only those letters that follow slash "/" i.e.

```
desired_output = ['b','d','f']
```

A code would be very helpful.

Comment: how did u create such a list?it should give errors

Comment: This is the list of file names I got using the tar.getmembers().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have this input.You can get by simple list comprehension.

```
input = ["a/b", "g", "c/d", "h", "e/f"]
print [i.split("/")[1] for i in input if i.find("/")==1 ]
```

or

```
print [i.split("/")[1] for i in input if "/" in i ]
```

> Output: ['b', 'd', 'f']

Comment: Oops, sorry. You beat me too it!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter u need to be proactive scripter :P

Answer (score 2):

With regex:

```
>>> from re import match
>>> input = ['a/b', 'g', 'c/d', 'h', 'e/f', '/', 'a/']
>>> [m.groups()[0] for m in (match(".*/([\w+]$)", item) for item in input) if m]
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner could be to:

```
>> input = ["a/b", "g", "c/d", "h", "e/f"]
>> list(map(lambda x: x.split("/")[1], filter(lambda x: x.find("/")==1, input)))
Result: ['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>  input = ["a/b", "g", "c/d", "h", "e/f"]
>>>  output=[]
>>>  for i in input:
         if '/' in i:
             s=i.split('/')
             output.append(s[1])

>>>  output
['b', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your list by having all strings encapsulated by "", you can then use this to get what you want.

```
input = ["a/b", "g", "c/d", "h", "e/f"]

output = []
for i in input:
    if "/" in i:
        output.append(i.split("/")[1])

print output
['b', 'd', 'f']
```